# iOS webrtc app using cordova-plugin-iosrtc: video element issues

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, webrtc, cordova-plugins

I'm developing an hybrid app for iOS using ionic/cordova. This app implements some typical webrtc features such as **video calls** and file transfers between two peers.
For this purpose I'm using [cordova-plugin-iosrtc](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc) which exposes all W3C WebRTC APIs.

While RTCPeerConnection, getUserMedia and other Javascript WebRTC APIs implementations are pretty good, otherwise the `video` element to which streams are attached is substituted by a native `UIView` layer (see [Usage](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc#usage)).

*This way you can't completely control via JS the pseudo-video element (that is `UIView`). For example it's not possible to resize the video, position it, change all its CSS properties and so on.* `UIView` size and position are set at initial value of HTML video element.

Is there a workaround or an alternative to this limitation (opened as an [issue](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/issues/38)) of iosrtc cordova plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the video element is not an actual HTML DOM element displays the video, however the library mimics the CSS of the video element to the best of its ability (for dimensions and positioning).

You can still manipulate the video element using JavaScript, but you must call an `iosrtc` method to update the `UIView` afterwards Using:

`iosrtc.refreshVideos()`

More information can be found here: https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/docs/iosrtc.md#iosrtcrefreshvideos

Comment: I know all these features and used it in my project. However the limitations of this approach still remain and this fact forces to have two different project, one for Android and one for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

cordova plugin iosrtc is updated and fixed the issue according to https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/pull/179.

Update the plugin and it will solve the issue.